# Unable to send message to select! loop via an mpsc::unbounded_channel

Tags: asynchronous, rust, redis, mpsc

I have an issue with a Redis client which I'm trying to integrate into a larger message broker.

The problem is that I am using the PUBSUB functionality of Redis in order to subscribe to a topic and the `async` implementation [shown in the docs example](https://github.com/redis-rs/redis-rs/blob/36b9173d8f4d974361c8c55111e3858c34e99b71/redis/examples/async-pub-sub.rs#L15) does not properly react to disconnects from the server.

Basically doing a `loop { tokio::select!{ Some(msg) = pubsub_stream.next() => { handle_message(msg); } } }` would properly handle new messages, but when the server went down or got unreachable, I would not get notified and `pubsub_stream.next()` would wait forever on a dead connection. I assume that the client would then drop this connection as soon as a command would get sent to Redis, but this is a listen-only service with no intention to issue other commands.

So I tried to use an approach which I learned while adding WebSocket support via `axum` to this broker, where an unbound mpsc channel is used to deliver messages to a specific WebSocket client, and there it works.

The following is the approach which I'm trying to get to work, but for some reason the code in the select! loop is never executed. I'm intending to add more code from other channels to the select! loop, but I've removed them to keep this example clean.

Basically I am seeing the  `- 1 REDIS subscription event` printouts but not the  `- 2 REDIS subscription event` printouts.

```rust
pub async fn redis_async_task(storage: Arc<Storage>) {

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    let mut eb_broadcast_rx = storage.eb_broadcast_tx.subscribe();

    let (mpsc_tx, mut mpsc_rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel::<Msg>();

    let mut interval_5s = IntervalStream::new(tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_secs(5)));    

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    let _task = tokio::spawn({
        async move {
            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    Some(msg) = mpsc_rx.recv() => {
                        
                        // Why is this never called?
                        
                        let channel = msg.get_channel_name().to_string();
                        let payload = msg.get_payload::<String>().unwrap();
                        println!(" - 2 REDIS: subscription event: {} channel: {} payload: {}", channel, payload);
                    },
                    
                    Some(_ts) = interval_5s.next() => {
                        
                        // compute messages per second
                        
                        println!("timer");
                    },

                    Ok(evt) = eb_broadcast_rx.recv() => {
                      
                        // Some other events unrelated to Redis
                      
                        if let Event::WsClientConnected{id: _id, name: _name} = evt {}
                        else if let Event::WsClientDisconnected{id: _id, name: _name} = evt {}
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    loop {

        // loop which runs forever, reconnecting to Redis server upon disconnect
        // and resubscribing to the topic.

        println!("REDIS connecting");
        
        let client = redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1:6379/").unwrap();
        if let Ok(mut connection) = client.get_connection() {
            
            // We have a connection
            
            println!("REDIS connected");
            
            if let Err(error) = connection.subscribe(&["tokio"], |msg| {

                // We are subscribed to the topic and receiving messages
                  
                if let Ok(payload) = msg.get_payload::<String>() {
                    let channel = msg.get_channel_name().to_string();
                    
                    println!(" - 1 REDIS subscription event: channel: {} payload: {}", channel, payload);
                    

                    // Send the message through the channel into the select! loop
                    
                    if let Err(error) = mpsc_tx.send(msg) {
                        eprintln!("REDIS: error sending: {}", error);
                    }
                };
                // ControlFlow::Break(())
                ControlFlow::<i32>::Continue
            }) {
                
                // Connection to Redis is lost, subscription aborts
                
                eprintln!("REDIS subscription error: {:?} ", error);
            };
        } else {

            // Connection to Redis failed, is probably not reachable.
                
            println!("REDIS connection failed");
        }
        
        // Sleep for 1 second before reconnecting.
        
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    }
}
```

The code above is called from `main` like so, in parallel to other clients like WebSocket and MQTT, which do work.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
   
   // ...
   
   tokio::spawn(task_redis::redis_async_task(storage.clone()))
   
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I have many points of concern around this code. Why use `select!` when you only wait for one task? Why use `UnboundedReceiverStream` when you don't use any `Stream`-specific functionality? (`mpsc_rx.recv()` would do just fine) The `connection.subscribe()` call is not asynchronous so you're blocking a whole tokio worker thread when waiting for messages. If your goal is to make the original reference code auto-reconnect, why not just put that logic in a loop and call it a day? Why deal with the hassle of spawning a separate thread and using a channel to communicate?

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks! I modified it to use `mpsc_rx.recv()` directly, for some reason I was getting some errors which made me think I had to turn it into a stream (I'm new to Rust and Tokio). I probably forgot to add the `mut` to `mpsc_rx`. *I also added more example tasks* to make it clearer what I'm trying to archive. `task_redis` which contains `redis_async_task` is a separate file and I am attempting to isolate the tasks which occur in each file and only use events to communicate among them (like an EventBus) and I thought that doing this `select!` stuff is the cleanest way.

Comment: @kmdreko But you're right, that spawned task is blocked, since the `IntervalStream` isn't firing as well. How do I get around this?